# doPost method in servlet not getting called

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to override the doGet and doPost and trying to call the doPost but not working. Below is ths JSP and Servlet code

```
    <%@ page language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="FirstServlet">

<input type="text" name="Name" value="Enter">
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And Servlet code is below and trying to invoke the doPost method but it's not getting called and not printing the message in console. However when i try to access the servlet directly from URL, it's doGet method is getting called

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class FirstServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/FirstServlet")
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public FirstServlet() {
        super();
        System.out.println(" Inside Constructor");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
     */
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(" Inside init");
    }


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(" Inside doGet");
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(" Inside doPost");
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm using http://localhost:8080/Servlets/home.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML form submit button is incorrect: fix **type** attribute. 
Try:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: That's correct and it worked. Thanks mate. BTW what is difference between submit and button?

Comment: @JavaGeek, no problem. 'submit' is used for submitting form and browser will automatically perform request to the server, 'button' is just a UI button and in order to handle a click, you have to attach Javascript function to it.

Comment: @JavaGeek, good introduction to HTML forms: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form